# How to use document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 questions

1. Please help me understand some JavaScript to create an accordion menu I got from W3Schools

**css**

```
    <style>
button.accordion_f {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion_f.active, button.accordion_f:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: blue;
}

button.accordion_f:after {
    content: '\02795';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;       
    margin-left: 5px;  
}

button.accordion_f.active:after {
    color: blue;
    content: "\2796";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 14px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 6000px;  
}
</style>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_f");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");       
    }
}
</script>
```

**Example use**

```
<button class="accordion_f">3rd party compatibility</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Offers an easy way to connect your Polar training device with 3<sup>rd</sup> party services.</p>
</div>
```

This works correctly

If I encapsulate this in another class for example in a pill menu it will not expand the menu, the css seems to work, the background shading etc, when I inspect the element I do not see the script, is the parent class affecting document.getElementsByClassName some how?

```
<ul class="tabs">
<button class="accordion_f">3rd party compatibility</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Offers an easy way to connect your Polar training device with 3<sup>rd</sup> party services.</p>
</div>
</ul>
```

2. How do I put my script into a function and call it with onclick or onmouseover?

I tried:

```
<button class="accordion_f" onmouseover="accordion_menu()">Activity</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Tracks your daily activity at five intensity levels for 24 hours a day, seven days a week, and provides a complete picture of all of your activity. It counts your active time, daily burnt calories, steps, distance from steps and sleep.</p>
</div>

function accordion_menu(){
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion_f");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick.classList.toggle("active");        
    acc[i].onclick.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");        
 }
}
```

This just opened all panels with a class of accordion_f, not just the active one as I would like.

Comment: Put `<script>` in front of JS and `</script>` behind JS. So `<script> function....("show") } }</script>`

Comment: `How do I put my script into a function and call it with onclick or onmouseover` SO should not be your first port of call - if you Google that exact phrase you will find the answer

Comment: I have googled and tried as you can see, but my function is not working, i believe because it is creating a function, i may be wrong...

Comment: The function is in an external file, i only put it here like this to show you how i designed it.

Answer (score -1):

It is working, I.E was in compatibility mode and ie8 had poor support for document.getElementsByClassName